# CASE WHEN slow searching of results

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I wrote a Case statement into the below view.

```
SELECT Carrier, CASE Carrier WHEN 'CSNY' THEN 'TL' ELSE 'LTL' END AS Mode
FROM   dbo.View1
```

The problem happens when I search for the Mode named 'TL' it returns the expected 28 results but it takes 15 minutes and 45 seconds.

```
SELECT [Carrier],[Mode]
FROM [Test].[dbo].[ViewReport]
WHERE Mode = 'TL'
```

When I run the view wide open it returns results in 5 seconds with 6,856 results.

```
SELECT [Carrier] ,[Mode]
FROM [Test].[dbo].[ViewReport]
```

When I search for the Carrier named 'CSNY' it returns results in less than a second with 28 results. (It also shows on these results that the Mode is set to TL like it should be.)

```
SELECT [Carrier],[Mode]
FROM [Test].[dbo].[ViewReport]
WHERE Carrier = 'CSNY'
```

When I search for the Mode named 'LTL' it returns results in 6 seconds with 6828 results.

```
SELECT [Carrier],[Mode]
FROM [Test].[dbo].[ViewReport]
WHERE Mode = 'LTL'
```

I don't understand why searching Mode for 'TL' is taking so long and I am not sure how to even evaluate the cause. I have also tried rewriting the Case Statement as "CASE WHEN Carrier = 'CSNY' THEN 'TL' ELSE 'LTL' END AS Mode" but it didn't make any difference in the results. The results are what I am expecting them to be but I need to be able to search by that column and it needs to return the 28 results faster than 15 minutes. Any ideas are welcome. I am sorry if I said anything incorrectly, this is my first question on here and I can usually find an answer if I dig deep enough.

Comment: It's not clear what your actual query is - are you *nesting* views? Have you examined the execution plan?

Comment: Considering you are querying a `VIEW` and you've omitted the definition of that, we have no idea why it's slow. I would start by looking there.

Comment: Depends on the view, look up full text search.
And maybe try with LIKE

Comment: Side note, it is a `CASE` **expression**, not statement.

Comment: look into creating a computed column for that value so it persists and creating an index on it.  Short answer: the engine can't use an index on "Mode"  now as why LTL is faster.... might have to do with what's running in memory and precompiled values.  Execution plan is needed for detailed analysis. as stu indicated.

Comment: Here you need to create Non cluster index on Mode column, after that your result would be fast.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help! I was able to pin it down to a nested view. I know they are not good but my company has them throughout there server and I am just trying to make sense of it and can't fix it all at once. I was able to move the Case Statement to an earlier view and run it against actual tables instead of views. Works in seconds now. Thanks for the invaluable input, I would have been lost without it.